# Discord.py. How can I wait_for person's reaction inside "on_raw_reaction_add" function?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I need to get the reaction of the user from his private channel. Is this the right way to do that?

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    reactioneer = payload.member
    emoji = payload.emoji
    if emoji.name == "":
        msg = await reactioneer.send("Hi! Which greeting would you like to hear every morning? Click the reaction of it. Hello - 1, Morning - 2...")
        await msg.add_reaction(:one:)
        await msg.add_reaction(:two:)
        def check(user, payload):
            return user == payload.member and message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private
        await bot.wait_for("payload", check = check)
        ### some things with data bases (does not matter now)
        await reactioneer.send("Alright, I will send this greeting every morning!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
await bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", check=check)
```

[`bot.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) waits for a [WebSocket event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord-api-events) to be dispatched.